# Excel: input data validation to allow only numbers

Tags: excel, vba

Is there any way to not allow users enter alpha characters in a cell that I need only numbers?

I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: a format of #########

Comment: this is only the format for what was inputed, but alow enter "AABBAABBAAA"

Comment: what happens when you tab out?  those characters are still there?

Comment: the alpha still there... =/

Comment: Do you mean data validation?

Comment: Yes! sorry, I just edited the title... Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: what version of excel?   in Excel 2010 you can click on the data tab and click the data validation menu button and set it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned it can be achieved by Data Validation... **but there is a catch.**

**First method** : Data validation

1. ALT+D+L
2. Allow : Whole Number
3. Data : greater than (*select what you want*)
4. Minimum : 0

**CATCH :**
But Data Validation doesn't check the value if it is copied from some other cell.
That is, if I copy alpha value from a different cell & paste / paste special (value) it over the cell, **it will accept it**. It will not restrict me.

Hence **Second Method** : VBA

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const CELL_ADDRESS = "$A$1" 'change cell
    If Target.Address = CELL_ADDRESS Then
       If Not IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
          MsgBox "Wrong value", vbCritical, "666bytes"
          Target.Value = vbNullString
       End If
    End If
End Sub
```

**Edit**: For a range :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Const CELL_ADDRESS = "$D$2:$E$4000" 'change range
    If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range(CELL_ADDRESS)) Is Nothing Then
       If Not IsNumeric(Target.Value) Then
          MsgBox "Wrong value", vbCritical, "666bytes"
          Target.Value = vbNullString
       End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Insert this VBA code in the sheet module where you want to implement this and change CELL_ADDRESS.
If you want you can do a lot of stuff using the Worksheet_Change event, so please play as you like with this code. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Could CELL_ADDRESS be a range like this? "D2:E4000"

Comment: @UderMoreira : Yup! you can but with area intersection method. I have edited my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming input cell is A1

In the Data Validation menu

Allow: Custom

Formula: =isnumber(A1)